# Weird gradient on my jQuery mobile site on a Windows Phone device

Tags: jquery-ui, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I created a simple jQuery mobile website and when I view this website on a Windows Phone there is a weird gradient between my footer and my content. It only occurs on a Windows Phone and I have no idea how it gets there.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vPqZ.jpg

**CSS**

```
        .ui-page 
        {
            background-color: white;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .ui-content
        {
            background-color: white;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .ui-footer 
        {
            position: absolute !important;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

**HTML Example plage**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="Diensten">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Diensten</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content"> 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>
                    Proofreading
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Hebt u een tekst (brochure, webtekst, mailing,...) die u nog even wilt laten nalezen? Geen probleem, wij hebben proofreaders voor alle talen van de Europese Unie, het Russiche, Chinees en Japans. Wij zorgen ervoor dat uw tekst klaar is voor publicatie of verspreiding.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                    Taaladvies
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Aangezien onze pool van vertalers en revisoren uit mensen bestaat die een taalkundige opleiding hebben genoten, zijn zij ook uitstekend geplaatst om u taaladvies te verstrekken.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>       
          </div>
          <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
            <p>&copy; No Problem</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install weinre and check the classes assigned to that part of HTML. It will help you find that class.

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-debug-windows-phone-html5-apps.html

Because JQueryMobile assigns lots of classes to each element, those are not all:

```
.ui-page 
    {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .ui-content
    {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .ui-footer 
    {
        position: absolute !important;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```